# On pressing back button in MainActivity page refreshers

Tags: android, android-layout

I am navigating Activity A to B, then B to A. So now I am in Activity A, if I press back button here, the page refreshes to Activity A again, not closing app. And if i press back again only then it is closing.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Main2Activity.class just call finish() within onClick method so you navigate back to previous activity.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish(); 
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You didn't understand my question. After coming back to activity A, when i press back, it is refreshing activity A, I don't want to refresh, i want to quit.

Comment: @R.H I have understood  your question perfectly, if you execute my code you will get the behavior you are looking for

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry i didn't listen you for first time.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish(); //just this. it will go to previous activity
            //onBackPressed(); also can
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want use the hardware back button you can try this;

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    // do something  
    super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

Comment: Code works perfectly with hardware back button, i was having problem with software back button, but now its solved, with just finish().